# How to convert komodo project to netbeans project?

Tags: php, netbeans, project, komodo

when i found our php project builded by komodo ide. it was hard adjust to control by the komodo set. so i want convert komodo project to netbeans. is there have any soluction?

How to convert komodo project to netbeans project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automated way to do this.

You can safely open up the KPF file in a text editor (even Komodo itself) to review the contents.  It's just XML.  Any non-default settings you've assigned for the project will be listed there.  Unless you've gone overboard and changed *everything*, it should be an amazingly trivial thing to simply manually make changes in Netbeans as required.